# Why can't Android Studio read the entire contents of my unzipped docx xml file?

Tags: android, xml

I'm using an InputFileStream in a BufferedReader to get lines of data out of an XML I unzipped out of a zip file:

```
iStream = mContext.assets.open("files/word/document.xml")
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(iStream))
        var line = reader.readLine()

        for (i in 0..50) {
            Log.d("Trace", line)
            line = reader.readLine()
        }
```

For some reason Android IDE is only able to read a few lines from the stream even through the xml file has hundreds of lines. If I open the file in a window in the IDE, it is the same story.

Can anyone tell me how to get ahold of the data here?

Comment: `Why can't Android Studio read the entire contents of my unzipped docx xml file?`. Is Android Studio reading that file? I think it is your Android app.

Comment: `For some reason Android IDE is only able to read...`. Your Android app you mean!